# Eclipse Words Autosuggestion

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete

Is there any way to have word autosuggestion in Eclipse for any text (Not just for .java, .php, etc. files) like Notepad++ does?
In the following example, Notepad++ suggest me the word "example" when I gonna type the same word for the second time:

[image]

I'm looking for the same feature in Eclipse.
I'm using Eclipse Platform 2018-09 version.